# SwiftUI NavigationLink style within ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a screen where I'm trying to display a list of `NavigationLink` and a grid of items (using `LazyVGrid`).  I first tried putting everything in a `List`, like this:

```swift
List() {
  ForEach(items) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: MyDestination()) {
      Text("Navigation link text")
    }
  }

  LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
    ForEach(gridItems) { gridItem in
      MyGridItem()
    }
  }
}
```

However, it seems that putting a `LazyVGrid` in a `List` doesn't load the items in the grid lazily, it loads them all at once.  So I replaced the `List` with a `ScrollView` and it works properly.  However, I do want to keep the style of the `NavigationLink` that is shown when they are in a `List`.  Basically what this looks like https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Screen-Shot-2019-10-05-at-3.00.34-PM.png instead of https://miro.medium.com/max/800/1*LT7ZwIaidXrMuR6pu1Jvgg.png.

How can this be achieved?  Or is there a way to put a `LazyVGrid` in a `List` and still have it load lazily?

Comment: List itself actually is already a lazy view. It does not load everything at once. For this case, if you want to keep the look of list with lazy loading, you could make a custom grid with HStack/VStack combine since LazyVGrid does not work in List.

Comment: It is styled by List, in case of ScrollView you have to style it manually adding modifiers to label.

Comment: @Asperi according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/defaultbuttonstyle/automatic, it says "If you create a button inside a container, like a List, the style resolves to the recommended style for buttons inside that container for that specific platform".  If that is also the case for `NavigationLink` in addition to Button, ideally that's what I would want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at this, the `List` is already a built-in Lazy load scroll view, you can check that is lazy on the `onAppear` event

```
import SwiftUI
struct item:Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct listTest: View {
    @State var items: [item]
    
    init () {
        var newItems = [item]()
        for i in 1...50 {
            newItems.append(item(value: "ITEM # \(i)"))
        }
        self.items =  newItems
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List($items) { $item in
                NavigationLink(destination: MyDestination(value: item.value)) {
                    Text("Navigation link text")
                        .onAppear{
                            print("IM ITEM: \(item.value)")
                        }
                        .id(UUID())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyDestination: View {
    
    let value: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("HI A DETAIL: \(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't address my question.  LazyVGrid does not load its contents lazily when it's in a List.